# Is there anything you could tell me? / Do you have anything to tell me?

Tags: questions

Am I right that the first question asks about a specific case which is known, but the second one - about something indefinite/uncertain?

> **Is there anything you could/can tell me**?

> **Do you have anything to tell me**?

Comment: The two questions are interchangeable for most purposes. One or other might fit a certain context better. But neither can be limited to a specific case. **Is there anything you can tell me about the arrival of the first peoples in the Pacific islands?** **Do you have anything to tell me about how the incident occurred?**

Comment: How do you choose which form is better to use in this kind of questions?

Comment: It's just a question of practice and experience of using the language. But with distinctions as fine as these, it really doesn't matter.